# Proving the correctness of calculating the amount of time between two dates

Tags: algorithm, loop-invariant, proof-of-correctness

I have a very simple function which is supposed to calculate the amount of time between 2 dates in given time units, e.g.: `getPartialPeriod(January 1, February 15, months)` would result in `1.5`.

I am really struggling with how to prove it - I started with the loop, because I think that's the most difficult part. I have defined numerous Hoare triples and loop invariants only to find out that they are all useless. I would appreciate all the help I can get with this.

The pseudocode of the function:

```
getPartialPeriod(startDate, endDate, timeUnitType):
    partialPeriod = 0
    currentDate = startDate + 1 timeUnit

    CASE timeUnitType
        weeks:   daysInTimeUnit = 7
        months:  daysInTimeUnit = 30
        DEFAULT: daysInTimeUnit = 1
    END CASE

    WHILE currentDate <= endDate DO 
        INCREMENT partialPeriod
        currentDate = currentDate + timeUnit
    END WHILE

    remainingPeriod = amount of days between currentDate and endDate
    partialPeriod = partialPeriod + remainingPeriod / daysInTimeUnit
```

P.S. Please ignore that it seems to be a bit of a silly implementation - that's not important.

Comment: It's pretty hard to prove, because the semantics of calendars are very very complicated (and change from country-to-country and from year-to-year). You would first specify the behaviour that you want.

Comment: Yeah I have noticed that working with dates does not make it easy. I have been trying to treat them like natural numbers (in a sense of adding one day to the date would increment it by 1).

Comment: The loop invariant is something like startDate + partialPeriod * timeUnit = currentDate, isn't it ?

Comment: That's what I mean by ignore the silly implementation :) Adding whole time units is more accurate (e.g. when going from February 14 to March 14, you only need to add 28 days instead of 30 to add a month to it), the last part is rounded up for simplicity.

Comment: startDate + (partialPeriod+1) * timeUnit = currentDate seems like a possibility, I was considering it but I was not sure if it's any good